# How to show a confirmation message before leaving a Tab in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My ionic 3 application has an ion-tabs with two Tabs. When switching from tab to tab, I need to show a confirmation message ( using AlertController ) to prevent the user from changing the current tab unless he confirms his choice. Is this possible in Ionic ?
I've tried showing a confirmation message when tab has been changing. However, I couldn't prevent the new tab from showing up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can realize such things using Nav guards. You can find them in the ionic-docs for the [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

The implementation may look something like this:

```
ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Alert',
      message: 'Please confirm ...',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            reject();
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: () => {
            resolve();
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    alert.present();
  });
}
```

Use `ionViewCanEnter()` as `ionViewCanLeave()` does currently [not work](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12485) (at least when working with tabs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to show the confirmation message with your solution only when I change the tab for the first time. The problem I'm facing is that the ionViewCanEnter hook is only firing once because the tabs view is actually only loading in once (  [more details](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9951) about this issue ). Have you have you encountered this issue ?

Comment: So the user has to confirm _every_ time he enters the tab? Sounds like bad usability. But if thats an ionic bug currently you will have to do some messy hack to implement this. Like intercepting the click on the tab, prevent default, show alert, .select() the tab manually if success.

Comment: Or you manually destroy the tab page after leaving it again so it is initialized again the next time.

Comment: Not every time. Actually, my application has two tabs, each tab contains a module with a set of pages. When leaving the first tab and on certain views ( for example editing a form ), I wanted the user to confirm his choice of switching to the second module ( tab ). I thought the ionViewCanLeave hook would solve the issue when leaving the pages that require a confirmation but unfortunately it didn't work. I will consider your suggestions and see if I can do some messy hack to implement it

Comment: Ok I see, unfortunately I don't see another solution currently than hacking around it some way. Hopefully the ionic-team will fix these issues with version 4 of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

ionViewCanEnter just fire once when switch tab in first time.

You can use two way binding for tab root.

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" #myTabs>
    <ion-tab (ionSelect)="SwitchTab1()" tabIcon="pricetag" [(root)]="tab1" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab (ionSelect)="SwitchTab2()" tabIcon="attach" [(root)]="tab2" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The example in plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/FaoZTGZ9VDc8CSq4N9nL?p=preview

```
  SwitchTab2(){
    if (this.tab2 == null)
      this.Confirm('Are Sure For Switch To Tab 2 ?',() => {
        this.tab2 = Tab2;
        this.tab1 = null;
        setTimeout(() => this.tabRef.select(1));
      })
  }

  Confirm(Message, Action){
    this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: Message,
        buttons: [
          { text: 'Cancel' },
          {
            text: 'Sure',
            handler: Action
          }
        ]
      }).present();
  }
```